# C# Unit Test How to mocK IFormFileCollection?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, iformfile

I have a method that uses IFormFileCollection and i want to unit test it.

my method :

```
public IActionResultUploadBankAccount(){

 IFormFileCollection files = Request.Form.Files;
                if (!files.Any()) return Ok(new GeneralDto.Response("Check your files!"));
 // and my codes

}
```

and my authorize codes :

MockAuthorize.cs :

```
public static void Authorize(this ControllerBase controller,....){

//my codes
 var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("This is a text file");
            IFormFile file = new FormFile(new MemoryStream(bytes), 0, bytes.Length, "Data", @"\Mock\Images\testFile.jpg");


}
```

while i'm trying to test it, method throws error that says:

> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What am i doing wrong? or is there any way to test FormFileCollection?

Comment: No need to mock it since a simple default implementation [already exists](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/FormFileCollection.cs,9d0c106ab62511d6).  This is most likely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You need to show the code that is actually causing the problem so that we can help you accordingly

Answer (score 0):

As `FormFileCollection` is part of .NET, you shouldn't be testing it. Microsoft will have tested this functionality.

All you should be testing is your own logic.

In order to mock `IFormFileCollection` I would use a mocking framework such as [Moq](https://github.com/moq) and do something like this

```
private Mock<IFormFileCollection> _formFileCollectionMock;
private IClassToTest _sut;

public YourConstructor()
{
    _formFileCollectionMock= new Mock<IFormFileCollection>();
    _sut = new ClassToTest(_formFileCollectionMock.Object);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

put into test Setup or constructor:

```
var formFiles = new FormFileCollection();
var testBoundary = "--some-boundary-separator";     
var streamString = "";
streamString += $"{testBoundary}{nl}" +
    $"Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8{nl}{nl}" +
    File.ReadAllText("Data/info.xml") +            
    $"{nl}";
    
// use actual files in your Data/ folder
var f1 = new FileInfo("Data/file1.PDF");
var f2 = new FileInfo("Data/file2.PDF");

foreach (var fl in new[] { f1, f2 })
{
    var formFileMock = new Mock<IFormFile>();
    formFileMock.Setup(f => f.Name).Returns(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fl.Name));
    formFileMock.Setup(f => f.FileName).Returns(fl.Name);
    formFileMock.Setup(f => f.Length).Returns(fl.Length);
    formFileMock
        .Setup(f => f.CopyToAsync(It.IsAny<Stream>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .Returns(Task.FromResult(File.OpenRead(fl.FullName)));
    formFiles.Add(formFileMock.Object);

    //or add actual file:
    //formFiles.Add(new FormFile(File.OpenRead(fl.FullName), 0, 0, fl.Name, fl.Name));

    streamString += $"{nl}{testBoundary}{nl}" +
        $"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\"; filename=\"{fl.Name}\"{nl}" +
        $"Content-Type: application/pdf{nl}{nl}" +
        File.ReadAllText(fl.FullName);
}
streamString += $"{nl}{testBoundary}--";

httpContext.Request.Body = streamString.StringToStream();

var formCollectionMock = new Mock<IFormCollection>(); 
formCollectionMock.Setup(x => x.Files).Returns(formFiles);

httpContext.Request.Form = formCollectionMock.Object;

//httprequest to test:
request = httpContext.Request;var
```